# How to merge attributes fields and their values into a single table using a common key with FME

Tags: fme-form, merge

I am having difficulties with a relatively simple task. I have multiple transformers  which append an attribute to an "ElementID" coming from different transformers.
I would like to merge all outputs into a single table based on the ElementID field thus having a schema like "ElementID","Attribute01, Attribute02, Attribute03  instead of having 3 tables with ElementID, Attribute01 in table 1, and ElementID, Attribute02 in table 2 etc.

Not all ElementIDs have all three attributes..ie there will be missing attributes.

How do I achieve this with FME 2014.

Answer (score 3):

Should be simple. You have this:

[image]

And you need to get this:

[image]

Just:

- Add the attributes from tables 2 and 3 to table 1
- Delete tables 2 and 3
- Make connections to Table 1

Here's a short movie demo: http://screencast.com/t/0zKOWIrstTtG

Comment: Thank you Mark. This will create three records in Table1. Is there a way to merge all three attributes into one record?

Comment: Yes, the FeatureMerger transformer. Here I would merge using the ElementID as a join key. That would give me one record with three attributes.